# Python-Sphinx: setting text body font

Tags: css, fonts, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I have been trying to follow this example for selecting a font in Sphinx documentation:
https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started

I am using the "cloud" theme, and have put the following line in my conf.py file:

```
html_theme_options = { 
    "bodyfont": "PT Sans, sans-serif",
    "fontcssurl" : "//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans|Noticia+Text|Open+Sans|Droid+Sans+Mono|Roboto",
}
```

Additionally, I have tried putting the following into my _static/style.css file:

```
body {
  font-family: PT Sans, Roboto, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

Neither helps place the "PT Sans" font as the text.  Is this a browser issue?  How would I know which fonts I can build with from the available google list?

---

Answer (score 0):

In the [Cloud Sphinx theme documentation](https://cloud-sptheme.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cloud_theme.html#styling), there is a note:

> Note There are a number of options for changing the various colors and fonts used by this theme, which are still undocumented. A complete list can be found in the theme’s configuration file ([`/cloud_sptheme/themes/cloud/theme.conf`](https://bitbucket.org/ecollins/cloud_sptheme/src/default/cloud_sptheme/themes/cloud/theme.conf)).

Which leads one to this snippet.

```
# font css url - for loading in fonts (eg google font dir)
fontcssurl = //fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noticia+Text|Open+Sans|Droid+Sans+Mono
```

Try changing the font URL and all referenced font names above the snippet in `conf.py` and see if that works.  If not, then you can always use a theme override.